# Is this “it” a preparatory subject?

Tags: grammar

> “It may be that you do not like his art, but at all events you can hardly refuse it the tribute of your interest. He disturbs and arrests. The time has passed when he was an object of ridicule, and **it** is no longer a mark of eccentricity **to defend** or of perversity **to extol him**.”

— Moon and Sixpence by W. Somerset [Moon and Sixpence](https://a.co/cvxQVOO)

Is this **it** a preparatory subject and are **to defend** and **to extol him** the real subjects?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that terminology is used here:
[Wikipedia *preparatory subject*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preparatory_subject)

The structure is also called *subject extraposition*, using a dummy pronoun *it*.
[Google Books Student's Introduction to English Grammar *subject extraposition*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA247&dq=%22clauses%20with%20a%20subordinate%20clause%20subject%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWqe6tibrzAhXERvEDHVZUArkQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=%22clauses%20with%20a%20subordinate%20clause%20subject%22&f=false)

> 3. 1 Subject extraposition
>    Clauses with a subordinate clause subject generally have variants with
>    the subordinate clause at the end and dummy **it** as subject:

It is also called just *dummy subject*:
[Cambridge.org *It as Dummy Subject*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects)

> It’s always interesting to find out about your family history.

The structure in your example is a little more complicated. It could be expanded like this:
to defend [him] is no longer a mark of eccentricity
and
to extol him is no longer a mark of perversity

Elements are shared between the two phrases. It's beautiful.